# How to read data from Google Sheets using API in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api

This is a really specific question for those who have built chrome extensions using the Google Sheets API.

I've tried searching on stackoverflow but they all seem to be doing something different than what I'm asking, which is how to set up Google Sheets API in a chrome extension. I want my chrome extension in the contentScript.js to inject cell text as html an external Google Sheet similar to this [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). The spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit)

I can't find any posts or documentation on how to set up the API in a chrome extension. I see in the tutorial that it loads `<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"` in the inline script. Is this the API that lets you use the .gapi? Not sure how to incorporate this in the manifest so I can start using the Google Sheets API in my contentScript.js

Comment: Did you try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310904/how-to-read-data-from-google-sheets-using-api-in-a-chrome-extension), to be sure that it works for you? If so, adapt it to your needs. As a suggestion, you could use web app too, instead of chrome extension.

Comment: @JeffRush That link links back to this question I think. Also I am trying to develop a chrome extension so that is a requirement at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380137/6868879), user provided working example with source code and video presentation. Let me know if it helps you.