# Chrome Extension Manifest v3 MV3 authentication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-signin, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to use **Manifest version 3(MV3) to handle Google sign-ins on Chrome extensions**. How could i go about this, given that it's only mentioned in the docs that it [cannot be done](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: for anyone struggling with this, here is the code for an example using chrome.identity to get token and then use it with google/youtube api https://github.com/sturm-dev/chrome-extension-google-auth

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, with manifest v3 we cannot use the google sign popup for authorizing users. We should be using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/) API for authenticating the users with OAuth2 API services. I have used the google cloud platform to create the Oauth2 client id and token. Let me show you step by step process :

1. Create a project with [google cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. After creating the project you must create credentials for that project. Go to the credentials section and choose  OAuth client ID
   [image].
3. Next step is to get your extension id which can be easily found on the chrome://extensions page [image]
4. Now in "Create OAuth client id" section,choose “Chrome app” as the application type for the OAuth 2.0 client, and paste your extension ID into the Application ID field
   [image]
5. After creating it, you will get the client_id which needs to be used in our manifest.json file.

> ```
> "oauth2": {
>         "client_id": "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>         "scopes": []
>       }
> ```

6. To access the chrome.identity API in your chrome extension, add identity as in the permissions section

> "permissions": [
> "identity"
> ]

7. Finally, you can trigger the API by using the following method

```html
     chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function (token) {
        console.log(token);
      });
```

For further information , please checkout the article [here](https://medium.com/@elhardoum/implementing-firebase-auth-sso-with-google-in-chrome-extensions-with-manifest-v3-and-react-js-5946bca0ba19)

Comment: For more information, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/

Comment: for anyone struggling with this, here is the code for an example using chrome.identity to get token and then use it with google/youtube api https://github.com/sturm-dev/chrome-extension-google-auth

Comment: Chrome.identity.getAuthToken gives only token, not refresh token. So how do I refresh the token after it has expired? @EmmaAlecrim

Comment: Is there any solution for Opera? This code gives `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Function unsupported`, which led me to find that "Opera only supports the launchWebAuthFlow() Method in this API" per [their docs](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/apis/).