# How a Chrome Extensions involving OAuth 2.0 continue to be developed without completing the Google verification process?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-api-client

I'm developing a Chrome extension that involves OAuth 2.0 for Google API (gapi) authorization, allowing users to sync data to Google Sheets.

However, when I set everything up and try to update my extension, a Google authentication pop-up appears with the following message:

"Access blocked: {Your Extension} has not completed the Google verification process. {Your Extension} has not completed the Google verification process. The app is currently being tested and can only be accessed by developer-approved testers. If you think you should have access, contact the [developer](https://accounts.google.com/)."

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to continue developing my Chrome extension involving OAuth 2.0 without completing the Google verification process.

I have referred to the following developers' methods for setting up authorization in my extension:

1. bumbu's approach: "Using Google API (gapi) in Chrome Extensions (MV2)" [bumbu](https://bumbu.me/gapi-in-chrome-extension)
2. minni minhaj's approach: "Chrome Extensions (MV3) to handle Google sign-ins" [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514608/google-chrome-extension-manifest-version-3-to-handle-google-sign-ins/73345256#73345256)
3. ismail's approach: "Implementing Firebase Auth SSO with Google in Chrome Extensions with Manifest V3 and React.js" [medium](https://medium.com/@elhardoum/implementing-firebase-auth-sso-with-google-in-chrome-extensions-with-manifest-v3-and-react-js-5946bca0ba19)