# How to get google account info in Chrome Extension v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

follow this link [Chrome Extension Manifest v3 MV3 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72514608/chrome-extension-manifest-v3-mv3-authentication), I have get authToken from `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive':true },function (token){console.log(token);});`.

But how can I use the token to get account info?
I know from `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` I can get `id` and `email` field, but this not enough to me, if give more info like `avator`,`userName` is good to me.