# How can I query Google APIs using fetch/XHR calls in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api, fetch-api

I am developing a Google Chrome extension that interacts with Google Sheets. I am already able to retrieve an OAuth 2.0 token by letting my user sign into their Google account, and this token allows me to access the Google Sheets API. In particular, I can succesfully reproduce the code user Parth Kapadia provides in their Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74358255/20922744). This code allows me to create new Google Sheet file in my user's drive. However, I am unable to access any of the other functions of the Sheets API. In particular, the following code, which tries to change data in a spreadsheet,

```
data = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",  
        Authorization: "Bearer " + TOKEN
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        requests: [{
            repeatCell: {
                range: {
                    startColumnIndex: 0,
                    endColumnIndex: 1,
                    startRowIndex: 0,
                    endRowIndex: 1,
                    sheetId: spreadsheetId
                },
                cell: {
                    userEnteredValue: {
                    "numberValue": 10
                },
            },
            fields: "\*"
        }
    }]
}
fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/batchUpdate", data)
```

where TOKEN is the token I have retrieved and spreadsheetId is the id of the spreadsheet in question, returns the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". I took this code from this [blog article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/google-sheets-api-tutorial-with-javascript-588f581aa1d9).

I have also tried accessing other Sheets API commands, for example, [values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get), through the url

```js
const url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/A1:B2"
```

but this also returns an error (though apparently of a different nature; [this](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1_hBN2GARLwAXdole1rOtRYDUJ2XR6jjzcViulGIKY5c/batchUpdate) is the error I get for values.get, and [this](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1_hBN2GARLwAXdole1rOtRYDUJ2XR6jjzcViulGIKY5c/values/R1C1:R2C2) is the error I get for batchUpdate). What is going on here? Essentially, I am asking if anyone has figured out how to successfully access the full Google Sheets API from a Chrome Extension, now that Google enforces Manifest v3 and the security policies coming with it. It seems that user Parth Kapadia figured out how to do it (as they mentions in their Stackoverflow post linked above), but they only share one piece of code, for the createSheet method, and I couldn't make any other methods work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, a spreadsheet ID is used for both spreadsheet ID and sheet ID.

  - About sheet ID, you can see it at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).
- The endpoint is not correct.
- `data` is not enclosed.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const TOKEN = "###"; // Please set your access token.
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = "###"; // Please set your sheet ID.

const data = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    requests: [{
      repeatCell: {
        range: {
          startColumnIndex: 0,
          endColumnIndex: 1,
          startRowIndex: 0,
          endRowIndex: 1,
          sheetId: sheetId
        },
        cell: { userEnteredValue: { numberValue: 10 } },
        fields: "*"
      }
    }]
  })
};
fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + ":batchUpdate", data);
```

- When this script is run, a value of `10` is put into a cell "A1" of `sheetId` in `spreadsheetId`.

#### Note:

- This answer supposes that your access token can get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Google Sheets API Overview](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you very much! With your corrections the code works for me. What do you mean by "the endpoint is not correct" and "data is not enclosed"? And how do your modifications address this? While the code works now for me, I would like to understand why (from what I can see my confusing of spreadsheetId and sheetId is the only thing that mattered).

Comment: @querryman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `What do you mean by "the endpoint is not correct" and "data is not enclosed"?`, in your showing script, I think that `(` of `JSON.stringify({`, is not enclosed by `)`. But, in my answer, I modified it.